# Simplest git workflow for commits signing?

Tags: git, signing

Which would be the simplest git workflow for signing some commits, in order to mark them as having passed a given review, or a set of given reviews?

I suppose tagging them would create too many tags.
Creating an intermediate repository with a person responsible for committing (effectively using author/committer duality) would be a bit of overkill.

Is there any other way?
We generally use the common structure of remote branches for bigger chunks of work, and direct commits in master for simpler ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider rebasing those commits on top of a review branch, but that would change the SHA1 of said commit, which is bad if they are already pushed to other repos.

> Creating an intermediate repository with a person responsible for committing

This is why a push to a dedicated repo is certainly a valid solution, taking advantage of the publication workflow authorized by a DVCS (Distributed Version Control System).

You can then consider that repo as the "one referential", with the official code (i.e. code having been successfully reviewed).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [git notes](http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html) feature. It allows you to attach notes to commits without changing the original objects.

It's also supported [by GitHub](http://github.com/blog/707-git-notes-display).